# Destroy physics triggered GameObject in Unity ExecuteInEditMode

Tags: unity, c#

To destroy GameObjects I'm using this code :

```
try
        {
            DestroyImmediate(g);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Destroy(g);
        }
```

It is giving me error, something like this :

[image]

Full code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Road : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    void Start()
    {

    }
    void OnValidate()
    {
        foreach(GameObject g in gameObjects)
        {
            try
            {
                DestroyImmediate(g);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Destroy(g);
            }
        }
        gameObjects.Clear();
        foreach (Vector3 point in points)
        {
            GameObject tem = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            tem.transform.position = point;
            tem.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
            tem.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
            gameObjects.Add(tem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red you see in your console is not an exception, it's an internal unity error. so that try catch doesn't help.
You can't destroy gameObjects in that frame. You have to delay your call until the next frame. you can achieve this with coroutines.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Road : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector3> points = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    void Start()
    {

    }
    void OnValidate()
    {
        foreach(GameObject g in gameObjects)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DestroyGameObject(g));
        }
        gameObjects.Clear();
        foreach (Vector3 point in points)
        {
            GameObject tem = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            tem.transform.position = point;
            tem.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
            tem.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
            gameObjects.Add(tem);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DestroyGameObject(GameObject g) 
    {   
        yield return null;
        DestroyImmediate(g,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don’t want to wait until the next frame, you can wait until the end of the current frame and that should work. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForEndOfFrame.html